# Node.js fs module: Callback API vs Promises API performance difference

Tags: node.js, promise, callback, fs

Node's `fs` module [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_callback_example) contain this line (sic):

> The callback-based versions of the `fs` module APIs are preferable over the use of the promise APIs when maximal performance (both in terms of execution time and memory allocation are required).

No explanation is provided and I could find basically no info on this.

**So, why is `fs`'s Callback API more performant than Promises API and how big is the difference?**

**Update:** There is a relevant [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/37583) on github that I failed to find.

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/c65e492ad3d4057940ad76120d129f824d47503a#diff-11c13307cb334211e0d11f4e7e43bdc0a34e437779a63a6ff645e62448d973d2R100 Is the commit where this changed. You could ask the PR author where that comes from.

Comment: @Eli Add it as an answer and accept it, not as "Update".

Answer (score 0):

In this [Github comment](https://gist.github.com/weyoss/24f9ecbda175d943a48cb7ec38bde821?permalink_comment_id=4752197#gistcomment-4752197) it says, **array destructuring is hurting the performance** (when receiving values from "await"). It is observed 14% performance decrease on promise, and 31% loss on async/await.

But I don't understand why promise is slow. And sorry I don't have the knowledge to replicate it, since the script is requiring a `'./node/benchmark/common.js'` which I can't find it.